# Canjs observable list of records to automatically update DOM

Tags: canjs, canjs-list

How should I define observable object instead of {cases: records} in this code to update dom automatically once this observable is updated:

```
init : function( element , options ){
                    var el = this.element;debugger;
                    SObjectModelExt.findAll({sobject: new SObjectModel.Case()}).then(function(records){
                        el.html( can.view('casesView', {cases: records}));
                    });
                }
```

Is this can.Map({case: []}) or can.List?
How use it in the mustache helper?
{{#each cases }} ?

I've tried to use like

```
this.records = new can.Map({case: []});
el.html( can.view('casesView', {cases: records}));
```

and later in the code to do

```
this.records.attr('cases', entries);
```

but it doesn't update dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to initialize an empty [List](http://canjs.com/docs/can.List.html) and then [replace](http://canjs.com/docs/can.List.prototype.replace.html) it with the data you got back which should update the list. You can also assign that list for later reference:

```
init : function( element , options ){
    var el = this.element;
    var cases = this.cases = new can.List();

    SObjectModelExt.findAll({sobject: new SObjectModel.Case()}).then(function(records){
        cases.replace(records);
        el.html( can.view('casesView', { cases: cases }));
    });
}
```

Then you should just be able to reference it via `this.cases` later on and remove and add items to that list.

Comment: Thanks Daff for help! I faced with issue that replace of can.List is not reflected on DOM automatically. Here is my click handler: '#elId click' : function() {
                    var ctx = this;
                    SObjectModelExt.findAll({sobject: new SObjectModel.Case(), criteria: FILTERS['closed']}).then(function(records){
                        ctx.cases.replace(records);
                    });
                }

Comment: Looks like your click handler did not work because the button wasn't in the Controls element. This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/XU2Sd/1/